# como editar colores de tema claro y oscuro en material-ui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

estoy sando material-ui en una app de react, el tema es que los colores de los temas `light` y `dark` no me convencen, quiero hacerlos mas claros y mas oscuros, como podria editar esos colores, tengo una condiguracion basico por ahora:

```
const Theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: theme
  },
})
```

la variable `theme` viene desde redux, lo utilizo para que el usuario pueda cambiar de tema cuando lo desee.

Es una pregunta sencilla, simplemente quiero editar los colores del tema `light` y `dark`, como deberia hacerlo ?

Answer (score 1):

En la [documentación](https://material-ui.com/es/customization/theming/) indica que puedes generar un tema de la siguiente manera:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#abc000",
    // aqui se generan de manera automática las opciones light y dark. Pero si deseas las puedes editar aquí
      light: "#f12",
      dark: "#00ab56"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: green[500],
    },
//o también puedes agregar las opciones que deseas aquí
    light: "#f12",
    dark: "#00ab56"
  },
});
```